# kivy dynamically add and remove dropdown entries

Tags: python, kivy

my app should dynamically add and remove items in the dropdown menu. The adding of buttons works, but I didn't get it working to remove the added buttons.

py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    addButton = ObjectProperty(None)
    removeButton = ObjectProperty(None)
    top_layout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def resetBoxes(self):
        self.ids.btn_release.text = "Release"
        self.ids.btn_version.text = "Version"
        self.ids.btn_device.text = "Device"
        return

    def removeButtonPressed(self):
        self.dropdown.remove_widget(self)
        return

    def addButtonPressed(self):
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        notes = ['Features', 'Suggestions', 'Abreviations', 'Miscellaneous']
        for note in notes:
            btn = Button(text=note, size_hint_y=None, height=20)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
            self.ids.btn_release.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.ids.btn_release, 'text', x))
        return

    def btn_releaseClicked(self):
        self.ids.btn_release.text="clicked"
    def btn_versionClicked(self):
        self.ids.btn_version.text="clicked"
    def btn_deviceClicked(self):
        self.ids.btn_device.text="clicked"
class dropdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dropdApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    id: home_screen
    addButton: addButtonID
    removeButton: removeButtonID
    top_layout: topLayoutID

    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout: 
        size_hint: 1, 1
        Button:
            id: addButtonID
            text: 'Add'
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .70}
            size_hint: .3, .08
            valign: 'middle'
            halign: 'center'
            text_size: self.size
            on_release: root.addButtonPressed()
        Button:
            id: removeButtonID
            text: 'Remove'
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .60}
            size_hint: .3, .08
            valign: 'middle'
            halign: 'center'
            text_size: self.size
            on_release: root.removeButtonPressed()


    BoxLayout:
        id: topLayoutID
        size_hint: 1, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .90}
        Button:
            id: btn_release
            text: 'Release'
            on_press: root.btn_releaseClicked()
        Button:
            id: btn_version
            text: 'Version'
            on_press: root.btn_versionClicked()
        Button:
            id: btn_device
            text: 'Device'
            on_press: root.btn_deviceClicked()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`clear_widgets()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets) to get the result you want - removing all buttons from dropdown - or store some reference to those buttons in dropdown somewhere and remove only desired ones.

```
def removeButtonPressed(self):
    self.dropdown.clear_widgets()
```